# Gyro and accelerometer in Apple Watch

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

I like to get the gyro and accelerometer data of the Apple Watch streamed to the IPhone paired app (with highest possible refresh rate).
There does not seam to be an sdk for accessing the data?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Nope. The WatchKit SDK has no hardware access at this time.

Comment: Well that is a shame. But the hw specs do say it contains gyro and accelerometer I believe... Strange then that the api does not exist... Yet?

Comment: @HixField It's been speculated that this functionality is coming in the next version of WatchKit; right now, they're trying to keep things simple to go easy on battery life.

Comment: @AstroCB I hope :-) it would not make much sense to include the hw witout sw support ...

Comment: Does it changed since watchos 2 revealed,?

Comment: @user784625, see the answer below

Answer (score 9):

Sensor Data information is **now available** in `Watchkit for watchOS 2.0`.

You could check this information in the following session which is total 30 minutes presentation.If you do not want to watch entire session, then you directly jump to the `CoreMotion` and `HealthKit` features which is in between 22-28 min:

[**WatchKit for watchOS 2.0 Session in WWDC 2015**](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=105)

Here is the implementation in WatchKit Extension, here is the [reference](https://github.com/shu223/watchOS-2-Sampler/blob/master/watchOS2Sampler%20WatchKit%20Extension/AccelerometerInterfaceController.swift).

```
import WatchKit
import Foundation
import CoreMotion

class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {


    @IBOutlet weak var labelX: WKInterfaceLabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelY: WKInterfaceLabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelZ: WKInterfaceLabel!
    let motionManager = CMMotionManager()


    override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
        super.awakeWithContext(context)

        motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.1
    }

    override func willActivate() {
        super.willActivate()

        if (motionManager.accelerometerAvailable == true) {
            let handler:CMAccelerometerHandler = {(data: CMAccelerometerData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                self.labelX.setText(String(format: "%.2f", data!.acceleration.x))
                self.labelY.setText(String(format: "%.2f", data!.acceleration.y))
                self.labelZ.setText(String(format: "%.2f", data!.acceleration.z))
            }
            motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.currentQueue()!, withHandler: handler)
        }
        else {
            self.labelX.setText("not available")
            self.labelY.setText("not available")
            self.labelZ.setText("not available")
        }
    }

    override func didDeactivate() {
        super.didDeactivate()

        motionManager.stopAccelerometerUpdates()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks to quote my code:  https://github.com/shu223/watchOS-2-Sampler/blob/master/watchOS2Sampler%20WatchKit%20Extension/AccelerometerInterfaceController.swift  I would be glad if you introduce this link as a reference.

Comment: as you can see in shu233's code Gyro still doesn't work.